# Remove Ethereum wallet from Mac downloaded from GitHub

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet, geth-debugging

I'm looking to remove the Ethereum wallet I downloaded off of GitHub, from my Mac: https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases ...

I've pulled in the application to AppCleaner, in hopes that it would find all associated files, but it only adds up to 250MB - I was hoping the blockchain was detected by AppCleaner as i guess it takes up a large chunk of space?

How do I go about?

Some posts I've found direct to $HOME/Library/Ethereum ... but I can't find this folder...

Please help? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to find the geth folder under

```
/Users/"your username"/Library/Ethereum/geth
```

To find the Library quickly, open Finder and klick on "Go", then hold the option ⌥ key and "Library" should show up in the list.

Best, Ben